# Eclipse Tomcat file Synchronization

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, synchronization, vs-web-application-project

I am using Eclipse and Tomcat to develop some J2EE application, Dynamic web project

I am wondering how to synchronize the local files/file structure with the service side.

In practice, we develop our j2ee at a local workspace, but we need to upload these *.class to the service side, so done folder structure and other accessory files, such as web.xml.

Can somebody let me know how to configure Eclipse so that every action I made can also work on the service side?

such as generating *.class files to their destinated folder on service and mapping the folder structure onto the service side.

Many thanks